# Initializing a record without knowing its exact contents

Tags: ada

I have a source file in my project which comes from an external team, and I cannot modify it. It contains a record which defines the contents of a register:

```
type R_Field is (R_FALSE, R_TRUE) with Size => 1;
for R_Field use (R_FALSE => 16#0#, R_TRUE => 16#1#);
type W_Field is (W_FALSE, W_TRUE) with Size => 1;
for W_Field use (W_FALSE => 16#0#, W_TRUE => 16#1#);
type U_Field is (U_FALSE, U_TRUE) with Size => 1;
for U_Field use (U_FALSE => 16#0#, U_TRUE => 16#1#);
type My_Register is record
        R : R_Field;
        W : W_Field;
        U : U_Field;
end record with Size => 32, Object_Size => 32;

for My_Register use record
        R at 0 range 0 .. 0;
        W at 0 range 1 .. 1;
        U at 0 range 5 .. 5;
end record;
```

I am writing a driver which will be built against many different targets, each with it's own register file. For some variants of the register file, the My_Register record will not have the U field.

I am trying to initialize a My_Register record in my code in such a way that will set all the fields to 0. I want my code to work in both the case when U is defined and in the case when it is not.

I cannot do `reg : My_Register := (R => R_FALSE, W => W_FALSE, U => U_FALSE)` because this does not compile in the case when U and U_FALSE are not defined in the register file.

Is there a way to zero-init the entire record, the same way that `= {0}` would do in C?

Comment: I've seen some example code online which initializes records using `:= (others => <>);`. Does this guarantee a zero initialization?

Comment: It appears your external team has no foresight in their operations. The record should be default initialized to the FALSE values as part of the record definition. Also, operations on the different record types for different targets must themselves differ when sometimes the U field is omitted.

Comment: That is true. If we ever want to write a non-zero value to U, we would need to write code like 'if U_Exists then reg.U := some_value'. Unfortunately, this code will not compile for targets that don't have a U field because it will complain about reg.U not existing. Is there any way to code this logic and have it compile for both cases?

Answer (score 5):

So you have some code (a record type definition) that is different for different targets. Therefore your build system has some way to select the source files to be used for a chosen target. I advise you to make your record-initialization source code also different for different targets, making the build system select the proper source file for each target in the same way as it selects the proper source file containing the record-type declaration for that target. And the same applies to any code that has to access the U component if it is present.

The answer to your question if (others => <>) guarantees zero initialization is "no". It asks for *default* initialization of all components, so to get "zero" initialization the type for each component should have a default value of "zero" (or "R_FALSE", etc.), which would require adding a default-value aspect to the type declarations from the external team, something it seems you are not allowed to do.

If you don't want to use the target-specific source-file method, but you are sure that the size of the record is 32 bits for all targets, you can instantiate an Unchecked_Conversion function from "mod 2**32" to the record type, and apply that conversion to a zero value to get a record value with 32 zero bits. But of course Unchecked_Conversion is a hack that can lead to problems later on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will try these approaches. What kind of problems can using Unchecked_Conversion to zero out a record lead to? Isn't this identical to doing a memset-to-0 in C?

Comment: The Unchecked_Conversion is not quite identical to a memset (because the memset could, I believe, do a byte-by-byte set, which may not work well if the target is a memory-mapped control register). Sometimes Unchecked_Conversion is the right solution, and the problems that could occur are mainly maintenance problems: how sure are you that all future targets will have 32-bit registers? What happens if some target has a 48-bit or 64-bit register? An Ada compiler might warn you that the Unchecked_Conversion has a size conflict, or it might not.

Comment: As others have commented, the "right" solution for the original problem is for the target-specific declarations to provide target-specific initial values, either for each record component in the record type declaration, or as a an Initial_Value constant for the whole record. In other words, to have a better "target abstraction".

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [gnatprep](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugn/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#preprocessing-with-gnatprep) (preprocesses Ada code).

Answer (score 0):

The `(others => Value)` aggregate only works when all the fields have the same type; `(others => <>)` gives you the default values, which for this definition gives random values.

What you need is an abstract register type that your program may deal with regardless of the actual register type:

```
package Registers is
   type Abstract_Register is record
      R : Boolean := False;
      W : Boolean := False;
      U : Boolean := False;
   end record;

   procedure Op (Register : in Abstract_Register);
   -- Do something with a register
end Registers;
```

Then you have a different pkg body for each actual register type. If the actual doesn't have the U component, your operations simply ignore the U component of Abstract_Register. For your example:

```
package body Registers is
   type R_Field is (R_FALSE, R_TRUE) with Size => 1;
   for R_Field use (R_FALSE => 16#0#, R_TRUE => 16#1#);
   type W_Field is (W_FALSE, W_TRUE) with Size => 1;
   for W_Field use (W_FALSE => 16#0#, W_TRUE => 16#1#);
   type U_Field is (U_FALSE, U_TRUE) with Size => 1;
   for U_Field use (U_FALSE => 16#0#, U_TRUE => 16#1#);

   type My_Register is record
      R : R_Field;
      W : W_Field;
      U : U_Field;
   end record with Size => 32, Object_Size => 32;

   for My_Register use record
      R at 0 range 0 .. 0;
      W at 0 range 1 .. 1;
      U at 0 range 5 .. 5;
   end record;

   function To_Concrete (Register : in Abstract_Register) return My_Register is
      (R => R_Field'Val (Boolean'Pos (Register.R) ),
       W => W_Field'Val (Boolean'Pos (Register.W) ),
       U => U_Field'Val (Boolean'Pos (Register.R) ) );
   -- Alternatively, R => (if Register.R then R_True else R_False),

   function To_Abstract ...

   procedure Op (Register : in Abstract_Register) is
      Concrete : My_Register := To_Concrete (Register);
   ...
end Registers;
```

Comment: This approach would not be ideal for my specific case. I have an ads from the hardware team with thousands of registers, many of which have fields which may or may not be present. I would have to someohow parse it in my build process to determine which registers exist and then add the corresponding pkg body for each one. The code would be fragmented into many tiny files, each of which does a single register read/write

Comment: *One* `.ads` with *thousands* of registers? and fields which *may not be present*? (how do they say that in Ada?) I don’t understand how your hardware team are allowed to get away with that! (of course, if they’re customers all bets are off). Do you have a systems engineering team?

Comment: Ok, so thousands of registers. But how many different targets? That is, how many combinations of component present/absent in the different registers? Or can there be new such combinations whenever the HW team feels like defining a new target?

Comment: Right now, about 10 different targets, but this is likely to grow in the future. The hardware team may add new registers or fields in existing registers on future platforms as new features are added, and ideally, our code would be flexible enough to build on all of them. If we went with the approach of having a different package body for each possible version of a register contents, we would need the following: 1) a build-time script to parse the registers.ads and see which version of each register we have. 2) Select the correct adb which contains the code for r/w that register version.