# Writing to a register which may or may not exist in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a driver whose codebase is built for several targets, each with its own Registers.ads that defines the register set for that target. The driver needs to write to a register which may or may not exist in Registers.ads (depending on the configuration).

In C, I would do something like this:

```
#ifdef REG1
    reg_write(REG1, 0x1234);
#endif
```

In Ada though, there is no preprocessor and I can't do this with a regular if statement:

```
if REG1_EXISTS then
    reg_write(REG1, 0x1234);
end if;
```

This fails to compile on targets which do not have the register because REG1 is an undefined symbol.

Is there some way to achieve similar behavior to what the C code does? I could theoretically create a HAL with multiple implementations of a write_reg1 function, and select which one gets compiled based on the target, but I'd like to avoid this since there are a lot of registers like this and it would clutter up the code.

Comment: The abstraction approach I suggested for your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777688/initializing-a-record-without-knowing-its-exact-contents) should also handle this.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the HAL approach for the same reasons as in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

If REG1 does not exist in the particular target, you can still declare a dummy symbol REG1, with the right type, as long as you also declare REG1_EXISTS as False, or have some reserved value "No_Register" that lets you do

```
if REG1 /= No_Register then
   reg_write(REG1, ...)
end if;
```

If such register writes are very common, you could reduce the number of conditional statements by embedding the check for No_Register inside the reg_write operation.

Comment: I have tried the dummy symbol approach but I find that if I declare a local constant like REG1 : constant := 0, then its value is used instead of the real value in the case when the register does exist.

Comment: I intended for the dummy register to be defined in the same source file that would define the real register when the real register exists. If that source file is untouchable for some reason, you can instead put the dummy register in another package spec, but then you must use "use" clauses so as not to have to qualify the register name with the package name. Also, you will need different versions of that other package for targets without, and targets with, this register, with the dummy register defined, or not defined, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, we would need to parse the register file to see if the register is absent, and if it is, define it in another "dummy register" package. I'd like to avoid this kind of build-time complexity if possible.

Comment: If your targets have thousands of registers, and (it seems) new targets can pop up at any time, with new registers, or missing some registers, and new combinations of present or missing register components, it seems to me that it would be better to have a more data-driven or table-driven approach, instead of an Ada spec approach. The registers and their components would be defined in an input file (say, CSV format) and interpreted by your program. Then it would be easy to check "Does this target have register Reg123? Does register Reg345 have an X component?".

Comment: Btw, if you decide to parse the .ads file for a target, there are two off-the-shelf Ada parsing tools that could be useful: either the ASIS interface to the compiler's internal program representation, or the libadalang library from AdaCore. I've used neither, though, so I can't say if they would make it easier than writing a dedicated parser from scratch for the specific kind of .ads file that you have. If I had to write a parser, I would use the OpenToken Ada lexer/parser toolkit.